# Angular animation change src of img in custom order

Tags: angular, typescript, animation

Actually, I have 7 images with [att.src] and I need to animate them in concrete sequences like:

the first one, the first one and the second one, then the second and the third, the third and the fourth so on. When the animation ends, it should start from the beginning.

Basically, only two near elements (except the start, when only the first arrow has img_2 src) should have img_2 in src, the rest img_1.

My issue is, when I am trying to do that with rxJS, the animation is let's say half working, but the previous image doesn't come back to img_1 src.

Do you have any idea, how to do that?

```
    <div>
     <img class="first-arrow" [attr.src]="src$ | async"/>
     <img class="second-arrow" [attr.src]="src$ | async"/>
     <img class="third-arrow" [attr.src]="src$ | async"/>
     <img class="fourth-arrow" [attr.src]="src$ | async"/>
     <img class="fifth-arrow" [attr.src]="src$ | async"/>
     <img class="sixth-arrow" [attr.src]="src$ | async"/>
     <img class="seventh-arrow" [attr.src]="src$ | async"/>
   </div>

    src$: Observable<string> | undefined;
    isRedVisible = true;
    red = '1';
    yellow = '2';
    arrow1 = document.getElementsByClassName('first-arrow');
    arrow2 = document.getElementsByClassName('second-arrow');
    arrow3 = document.getElementsByClassName('third-arrow');
    arrow4 = document.getElementsByClassName('fourth-arrow');
    arrow5 = document.getElementsByClassName('fifth-arrow');
    arrow6 = document.getElementsByClassName('sixth-arrow');
    arrow7 = document.getElementsByClassName('seventh-arrow');

    arrowsArray: Array<any> = [];

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.arrowsArray.push(
            this.arrow1,
            this.arrow2,
            this.arrow3,
            this.arrow4,
            this.arrow5,
            this.arrow6,
            this.arrow7
        );
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.src$ = of('../../assets/img_1.png');
        from(this.arrowsArray.reverse())
            .pipe(concatMap(v => of(v)
                    .pipe(delay(500))),
                repeat()).subscribe(
            (item) => {
                setInterval(() => {
                    item[0].src = `../../assets/img_${this.yellow}.png`
                }, 500);
            },
            error => console.log(error),
            () => {});
    }
```

Comment: you can directly use carousel feature which is present in your bootstrap

Comment: but I need those arrows to be shown at the same time on the UI. :(

Comment: you can use this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/swiper